# Отключение управление принтерами в Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell

Может кто подскажет, существует ли команда PowerShell для снятия галки в списке принтеров "Разрешить Windows управлять принтером используемым по умолчанию", очень уж большая проблема когда принтеров несколько и компьютеров в сети много, а когда эта галка стоит Windows переодически "по своему хотению" перебрасывает печать на другой либо неподключенный принтер!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Судя по тому, что проблема возникает регулярно, Вы не можете в полной мере управлять этим параметром. Значит параметр задается политикой. То есть сверху накатывается политика домена? Если так, то может проще выставлять нужный принтер по-умолчанию вручную или с помощью скрипта?